# Android accessibility, camera switches, accommodating new comfortable or comforting navigation modalities

Tags: accessibility, camera-switches

Android comes with an accessibility feature called Camera Switches, which is designed to help people with motor impairment, who can only move some of their eyes (up, right, left), eyebrows (up), or mouth (open), to control navigation and input and selection though a mobile phone.

I was wondering, whether it is possible, to glue a widget, above the user interface (the entire user interface frame is pushed down, leaving space for this widget at the top).

With this widget, I can raise my eyebrows up, and, with such moment, control what "eyes up" does.

The widget consists of a number of squares, which can grow and shrink, (according, to mood, time, and, as these explain, needs).

When I raise my eyebrow, the selected square moves from left to right, in a circular fashion.

The last two squares can be used to grow or shrink the number of squares, and can be selected by opening the mouth on the square before it.

When this is done, the next two squares become accessible and allow you to add our remove squares.

So, for the rest (to the left), each square determines what an eyes up does.

So, once a square is selected, you can navigate with what an eyes up does, and use the remaining eyes left, eyes right, and mouth open, to navigate.

This, is just one possibility.

It, suggests, that we may want to have the capability to install a separate window manager layer on top of the switch access layer, to ensure, navigation, meets needs, and is comfortable.

The user can, that way, gain some satisfaction in the fact that the navigation modality is accommodable, and, feels good.

Does Android currently support adding on such behavior?

Thank you for your answers.